# Using multiple Google accounts in device but don't want some of them to show up anywhere in Hangouts app's menu

Tags: gmail, google-hangouts

I have five different Google accounts (my personal Gmail account used as the primary account and others for different Google Apps for Business email addresses), Gmail, Hangouts, and more, all work fine for each account. However, I don't use Hangouts on three of the accounts, and I'd prefer that I not even see these accounts in the Hangouts app.

While I can sign out of the unused accounts they still show up in the menu in the Hangouts app. Is there anyway to disable the Hangouts app entirely for specific Google accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not. The Google Account system in Android is an all-or-nothing setup. If the account is configured on your device, and a Google app supports it, then it will be listed as an available option, even if you turn off syncing of that component in the settings.

Comment: Thanks, figured as much, good to know I wasn't missing something.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Signing out is possible, see e.g. Leonardo's answer below (tested with Hangouts v10.0, last updated 8 June 2016).

Comment: That wasn't the case when this answer was written. Signing out didn't remove it from the list.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. Just open Hangouts> tap the three horizontal bars on the top left> tap the Settings option> select the account you'd like to remove> scroll down and select Sign out.
This will sign the account of Hangouts only. You will continue to receive emails and everything else for that account as usual.